# Best Practices for RH Properties

Tags: redhawksdr

I have a few questions regarding best practices for RH blocks.

First off, is there a block in the redhawksdr github that serves as an example that all RH blocks should follow with regards to how things should be done? I see many blocks in the redhawksdr gitub site and each seems to do things like logging and error handling a different way. Some have not removed the default generated logging statements yet.

Should we log all property changes? With the new property callbacks in 1.10 it would be easy to log the transitions from the old to the new. If so, what logging level should I log them to (e.g. DEBUG or INFO)? What are others doing and why?

In the event that an attempt is made to set a property, but the new settings cannot be applied, should we throw exceptions and ignore the new setting? Should we log an error or a warning and ensure no exceptions propagate out from our components? What log level should these messages be at? I see some blocks on github that print to cerr and do nothing else. What is the recommended approach used by those who are already using RH in practice?

In general, should we make our blocks so that property changes are transactions where either it occurs completely or the internal state of the block does not change at all. In some of the blocks on github for redhawksdr they will attempt a property change and print an error but the state is not really well defined at this point. Is this acceptable in general or should we make everything completely transaction level safe in this regard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When it come to best practices for component development, REDHAWK tends to emphasize freedom over conformity. Different components are developed with different use cases in mind, and there are many different approaches to solving problems in REDHAWK. This accounts for some of the differences you see between some of the components.

***Is there a recommended REDHAWK component that can serve as a standard:***
Taken as a whole, the REDHAWK components posted on GitHub attempt to serve two purposes. They are a collection of useful components for processing. And, they are meant as a set of examples for others to follow.

It is hard to pick out one component as the single best example, as they are each written with a different purpose and have taken different approaches. The HardLimit component is probably the simplest example, so it can be helpful to understand the very basics for developing a component. The fastfilter component is more complex, and it demonstrates some of the more advanced concepts such as locking and property callbacks, and overriding configure for validation on properties which are interdependent.

***Logging best practices:***
In short, when developing REDHAWK components, it is considered best practice to use Logging instead in system.out/system.error.

More broadly, Logging can be a difficult subject in REDHAWK. There really are no hard and fast rules. In general, anything which happens "typically" (e.g - receiving a packet in the service function) should be logged at DEBUG or TRACE. Anything which is outside of "normal" operation should be logged as WARN. ERROR is used for unexpected situations which the component should not have. Feel free to follow the guidelines of log4cxx or log4j when making decisions about which level to use.

One common logging practice is to log a warning when the input Q flushes, and this is seen on many of the components. The base class implementations log property changes at TRACE, so it shouldn't be necessary for component developers to log all individual property changes themselves at a higher level. However, they may choose to log important properties in the property Callback if they choose to do so (probably DEBUG or INFO would be an appropriate level).

***Invalid property configurations:***
In REDHAWK, Invalid Configuration is to be thrown when a component is configured improperly. It is up to the developer to decide how their components handle an invalid property configuration regarding updating its internal state. It is a design decision for component developers to make. If you want to roll-back an invalid property, the property callback does provide a mechanism for property validation. For a float property "myProp", the code may look something like this:

```
void propChanged(const float *oldValue, const float *newValue)
{
    bool valid(true);
    // add custom logic to check the value here and set valid to false
    // For example, here is a check to ensure the property is postive:
    if (value<0)
        valid =false;
    if (!valid)
    {
        LOG_WARN(comp_i, "myProp received invalid value"<< *newValue);
        myProp=*oldValue; //reset property to original value 
        throw std::exception();
        //this causes base class to throw invalidConfiguration
    }

    //any additional logic for updating the component after the change goes here
}
```

In some cases, you may not want to reset the value to the oldValue, you might want to set it to a default value (e.g. - setting negative numbers to 0). These are all up to the discretion of the developer. In some cases, you may want to round a value to a specific tolerance (such as rounding to the nearest .001) and not throw invalid configuration at all.

***Thread safe property changes:***
Thread concurrency during property configuration is incredibly important and should be considered for all properties. The base classes use the mutex "propertySetAccess" to lock during configure and query, which provides a simple way to lock and keep ANY properties from changing simultaneous to additional processing. However, this is not the recommended behavior because there are different approaches to handling property concurrency, and locking for all property configuration updates is overkill in most cases. Additionally, it is worth noting that when locking this way, the lock is held during property callback, so it is not necessary for callbacks to reacquire the lock.

For some properties, it may not matter if the value changes in the middle of processing a packet of data. A good example are "upper_limit" and "lower_limit" in HardLimit. The developer decided it didn't matter for these values to change mid-processing, and there is no property concurrency for this component.

For some properties, such as "fftSize" in the fastfilter, the designer decided that they never wanted this value to change mid-processing. So, they have a separate mutex, "filterLock_", to prevent this from happening.

Another option, instead of locking, is to make a local copy of the property and then use that copy throughout the processing. When the property is changed mid-loop,  the new value will be applied in the next service function.